# handlerbar js extending arithmetic addition helper

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, helper

I wrote a helper to add currency in handlebar js. While this works for two items, how can I extend this to any number of items?

i.e,

```
{{total a b}}

Handlebars.registerHelper("total", function(a,b) {
  return "$"+(Number(a.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,"")) + Number(b.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,""))).toFixed(2).replace(/\d(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$&,');
});
```

to, n number of items. i.e,

```
{{total a b c d}}
```

How to write a helper to get something like that?

Comment: helpers can take in as many inputs as you want, here is an example with 4. http://jsfiddle.net/ckross01/5eSyL/ Is there something else you are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be what you're looking for

```
Handlebars.registerHelper("total", function(a,b) {    
  var nums = [].slice.call(arguments,0,-1);      
  var sum = nums.reduce(function(prev,next) {
    return prev + Number(next.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g, ""));
  },0);    
  return "$" + sum.toFixed(2).replace(/\d(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$&,');
});
```

You can test this in [tryhandlebarsjs](http://tryhandlebarsjs.com/) with the following context and template

```
{ 
  "a": "10",
  "b": "20",
  "c": "30",
  "d": "40" 
}

{{total a b c d}}
```

Inside a helper you will have an additional `options` object along with the arguments. The `options` object is the last argument. So first we need to get a list of the passed arguments without the `options`.

[`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) is a javascript keyword that is accessible inside a function. Its an array like object that holds all the passed arguments. Since it doesn't have a slice method, we are using array's slice method. We execute that method in the context of the arguments ([`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)). So we use this line

```
var nums = [].slice.call(arguments,0,-1);
```

In the next lines we simply loop the array using the built in [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method.

The rest of the code self explanatory.

Comment: I've added a small explanation.